# Table heading and \tikzpicture cells are not vertically centered in tabularray package, and \polylongdiv is not working in a table environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, tabularray, polynom

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
\large

\newenvironment{tablemath}
    {
    \begin{array}{@{} l}
    }
    {
    \end{array}
    }

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={Q[c,m, wd=1.5cm] Q[l,m, wd=9.5cm, mode=dmath]
                      Q[r,m, wd=1cm, font=\bfseries] Q[l, m, wd=4.5cm]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
             row{2-Z} ={rowsep=7pt},
             }
    \SetRow{gray!20} A & B & C & D \\
    Regular Row & \begin{tablemath}
                  f(3) = 100  \\
                  a = \dfrac{50}{21} - \dfrac{13}{42}b
                  \end{tablemath} & C1 & D1 \\
    Tikz Row & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
                      \draw[thick,<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
                      \draw[thick] (0,0.1) -- (0,-0.1) node[anchor=north] {$0$};
                      \draw[thick] (-1.5,0.1) -- (-1.5,-0.1) node[anchor=north] {$-1.5$};
                      \draw[thick] (-1.5,0.25) -- (0,0.25);
                      \draw[fill=white] (-1.5,0.25) circle (0.05);
                      \draw[fill=white] (0,0.25) circle (0.05);
                      \end{tikzpicture} & \textbf{C2} & D2 \\
    Long Division Row & \polylongdiv{5x^5-4x^4+25x^3-x^2+36x-2}{x^3-x^2+3x-3} & \textbf{C3} & D3 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\polylongdiv{5x^5-4x^4+25x^3-x^2+36x-2}{x^3-x^2+3x-3}
    
\end{document}
```

The above code gives the following result:
[image]

The table heading (ABCD row) and \tikzpicture (Tikz Row) cells are not vertically centered. **Can anyone show me how to vertically center these rows?**

The \polylongdiv command does not work in this table environment as well, but it works otherwise (as shown outside the table). **Can someone also help in getting the command to work as such? (While maintaining vertical centering as well)**

Comment: Those are two very different questions. I don't know about the `tblr` environment but you can try adding `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` to the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: There are over 36 errors popping up when compiling your code. This isn't great for others trying to help at all. Why do you need to use `tabulararray`?

I think regular tables are better for weird configurations as it has fewer default smart configuration tactics.

Comment: The header row would be vertically cantered if there were descenders in the text. If you have no descenders in the whole header and you want it to be visually centered, then you can decrease the `belowsep` of that row, e.g. `belowsep=0p`.

Comment: @Michel Please refer to my previous question thread. (I used the answer marked as accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

- Column headers are vertical centered. To see this add to headers texts letters with descents as are g, j, p, ... If in column headers texts contain only capital letters, than you may add to `row{1}` specifications also  `abovesep+=2pt`, which will vertical centered such column headers (see MWE below).
- For image: to `tikzpicture` you need add option `baseline`.
- For `\polylongdiv` you need to do the following:

  - increase column width, for example for it use `X` column and reduce width of last column from 4.5cm to 3.5cm,
  - locally shift `\polylongdiv` equation to top of cell (by locally prescribed option `h`),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
\large

\newenvironment{tablemath}
    {
    \begin{array}{@{} l}
    }
    {
    \end{array}
    }

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec= {Q[c,m, wd=1.5cm] X[l,m, mode=dmath]
                       Q[r,m, wd=1cm, font=\bfseries] Q[l, m, wd=3.5cm]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text, bg=gray!20, abovesep+=2pt},
             row{2-Z} ={rowsep=7pt},
             }
A   & B & C & D \\
Regular Row 
    &   \begin{tablemath}
            f(3) = 100  \\
            a = \dfrac{50}{21} - \dfrac{13}{42}b
        \end{tablemath}     & C1            & D1 \\
Tikz Row 
    &   \begin{tikzpicture}[c/.tip = {{Circle[open, length=0 8, sep=-3.2]}},
                            font=\small, baseline=-1ex]
            \draw[thick,<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
            \draw[thick] (0,0.1) -- (0,-0.1) node[below] {$0$};
            \draw[thick] (-1.5,0.1) -- (-1.5,-0.1) node[below] {$-1.5$};
            \draw[thick,c-c] (-1.5,0.4) -- (0,0.4);
        \end{tikzpicture}   &  C2           & D2 \\
Long Division Row 
    &   \SetCell{h}
        \polylongdiv{5x^5-4x^4+25x^3-x^2+36x-2}{x^3-x^2+3x-3} 
                            &   C3          & D3 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\polylongdiv{5x^5-4x^4+25x^3-x^2+36x-2}{x^3-x^2+3x-3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get \SetCell{h} to work - are there any alternatives or fixes you can suggest? Is it also possible to vertically center the tikz row?

Comment: With the package adjustbox and \adjustbox{valign=m}{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}} for the vertically center

Comment: @pascal974 Upon trying the command, everything became centered except for the tikzpicture itself. Is there a way to also vertically center it as well?

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification, which version of `tabularray` you have? all version from 2022 support `h` ang `f ` table cells options. Try to upgrade your installation, You can also test proposed solution on Overleaf. BTW, tikzpicture is vertical centered ... so jo not need additional package and box for image...

Comment: @Zarko I use XeLaTex in Overleaf. I believe it should have the latest update?

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification,  unfortunately in Overleaf packages `\polylongdiv` and `tabularray` (version 2022B 2022-06-01 with expl3.sty    2022-08-05 L3 programming layer) are not compatible. In my test I use newer `tabularray`   2022C 2022-07-01 with expl3.sty    2022-10-26 L3 programming layer. I suggest you to ask Overleaf support for help (how to locally instal new versions  of those packages). Sorry.

Comment: @Zarko It's alright, I will see what I can do, but is it possible to vertically center the tikz row?

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification, this row is vertically centered, but <ou like to have it more pedantic, add to `tikzpiture` option  `baseline=-1ex`. See edit3d answer.

Comment: @Zarko That will be sufficient, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To better see the problem, I add the option `draw` in the node and `\vrule` after the `tikzpicture`

[image]

With `outer sep=20pt`

[image]

With `\adjustbox{valign=m}{`

[image]

Without `\adjustbox{valign=m}{` with ,`inner sep=0pt,yshift=-2pt`

[image]

With the **CODE** of zarko

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularray}

    \UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
    \usepackage{polynom}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}
    \large

    \newenvironment{tablemath}
        {
        \begin{array}{@{} l}
        }
        {
        \end{array}
        }

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                colspec= {Q[c,m, wd=1.5cm] X[l,m]},
                row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text, bg=gray!20},
                row{2-Z} ={rowsep=7pt},
                }
    A  & B\\
    Tikz Row
    &
    %\adjustbox{valign=m}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[c/.tip = {{Circle[open, length=0 8, sep=-3.2]}},
                font=\small, baseline]
                %\draw(0,0)--(0,-0.7);
                \draw[thick,<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
                % \draw[thick] (0,0.1) -- (0,-0.1) node[below,draw,inner sep=0pt,yshift=-2pt] {$0$};
                % \draw[thick] (-1.5,0.1) -- (-1.5,-0.1) node[below,draw,inner sep=0pt,yshift=-2pt] {$-1.5$};
                \draw[thick] (0,0.1) -- (0,-0.1) node[below,inner sep=0pt,yshift=-2pt] {$0$};
                \draw[thick] (-1.5,0.1) -- (-1.5,-0.1) node[below,inner sep=0pt,yshift=-2pt] {$-1.5$};
                \draw[thick,c-c] (-1.5,0.4) -- (0,0.4);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
            \vrule
            %}% 
    \end{tblr}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I understand now, thanks!